# How to disable the Norton Internet Security Reminder without uninstall Norton completely?

Tags: norton-antivirus, norton-internet-security

With Dell's purchase I was given a subscription of Norton Internet Security Subscription for 60 days (or 3 months)... I think after 60 days, the virus DB can not be updated, but the virus scanning ability is supposed to stay.

But it nags you every day to Renew.  How can a user disable it to never show again, without uninstalling Norton completely?

A virus can abuse a general user's computer, do bad things, anything that a user is not willing.

And Norton Internet Security, after expiration, will nag you every day, not giving you a "close button" to close the window, so the only easy way is to "Renew now", or else it makes you click the list, select "Remind me later" and click OK, and it doesn't give you a choice for "Never remind again".   How is it that much different from a virus in terms of "forcing its power onto you"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its been asked before and Symantec seems to think it's [a feature, not a bug](http://community.norton.com/t5/Norton-Internet-Security-Norton/Disabling-NIS-2008-Nag-Screen/td-p/32539) -- so it's unlikely that there's any way to remove it.

Norton's primary aim for the trial installs *is* to get people to keep on using their products, so it's in their interest to annoy you into doing so. There's a good many free, updated anti virus software -- my current favourite is microsoft security essentials - so switching to a free and less annoying product is probably your best choice.

Comment: aha... fits the description that the "good" is it, and the "evil" is it

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also. It keep popping up so after reading others comments someone mentioned that they didn't have this problem until they installed the Adobe Acrobat Reader. I uninstalled the Adobe Acrobat Reader and got rid of the Norton popup. So far it's been 2 days and it has stopped popping up. I run Windows 10 version. Some of you runs previous version and this may not work so you may have to upgrade to Windows 10 to get rid of the Norton popup.

Comment: So, to get rid of the annoying pop-up, you have to get rid of the ability to read PDF files? (Unless you know of any other software that can let you read them; I don't.) How is that a good thing?